# Problem related to dll

Tags: c++, c, dll, windows-ce, platform-builder

Can anyone guide me what could be the problem in the mentioned below:-

[alt text http://lh5.ggpht.com/_D1MfgvBDtsU/S5iLmYivj1I/AAAAAAAAABU/8Mquam_XxZ4/s912/dll%20issue.PNG](http://lh5.ggpht.com/_D1MfgvBDtsU/S5iLmYivj1I/AAAAAAAAABU/8Mquam_XxZ4/s912/dll%20issue.PNG)

This PP folder is present in the following path at my desk `"E:\WINCE600\PLATFORM\COMMON\SRC\SOC\COMMON_FSL_V2_PDK1_7\IPUV3"`

In this **IPUV3** folder, **PP** folder is present which does the **resize,rotation & conversion task** of an image. This **PP** folder consists of **PDK** & **SDK** . Inside **PDK** folder there is a file called **Ppclass.cpp** which i have modified.

> After modifying the Ppclass.cpp i have
>   rebuild the PP folder to check whether
>   in my project the modification is
>   reflected or not. But later i found
>   that the problem is of pp.dll which
>   even after the rebuild of PP folder
>   the new pp.dll is not highlighted.

Also the path for iMX51-EVK-PDK1_7 is as follows:

```
"E:\WINCE600\PLATFORM\iMX51-EVK-PDK1_7\target"
```

So now i want advice that how to sort this problem. I am sure that this problem is related to pp.dll

Please guide me to follow the correct step. I will be very thankful to u all.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your question is not clear, at least to me. Was everything OK before the change to source code?  
What is "Not highlighted" with regards to a Dll?  
Why did you write down the target folder path?

Comment: Bad, bad, bad, bad.  Never, ever modify the COMMON code tree.  Clone it to your platform.  If a QFE is released that fixes anything in that code, it will overwrite your changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was everything working as expected before the code change?
Are you getting any build errors?
Do you have a DIRS file in the IPUV3 directory that specifies the two subdirectories?

What is the problem? State what you did, what you expect and what was the outcome. It is not clear right now.

---

Update:
According to the comment below it seems that the build process is having trouble parsing one of your SOURCES files. From the error my guess is you have someting similar to:
`SOURCELIBS=E:\...`
Try:

```
SOURCELIBS=\  
E:\...
```

The `\` symbol tells the tool that there is are more values on the next line.

By the way, I don't know who wrote this on the SOURCES file, but I think it is bad practice to use absolute paths. You should use the macro for your platform path `_TARGETPLATROOT`. Use it like this: `$(_TARGETPLATROOT)\...`

Comment: I just modified Ppclass.cpp. And then rebuild the PP folder

Comment: After doing rebuild i have also rebuild the "iMX51-EVK-PDK1_7" which is present in the Platform directory

Comment: In rebuilding iMX51-EVK-PDK1_7 i got error stating this "statements that affect macro definitions might cause Build.exe to not rebuild modified source code. Refer to the Platform Builder documentation.
BUILD: [00:0000003679:ERRORE] CreateDirectory(SOURCELIBS=E:) failed. GetLastError=123 (dec)."

Comment: The error means: `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. ` From the Error lokkup tool inside Visual-Studio.